# Relatively prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was solving the following problem: given $a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, how many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$. I was trying to solve it in the following way:

Assume $gcd(a,b)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider $a-bi$. If $(a+bi)$ and $(a-bi)$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ then by Chinese Remainder theorem we have isomorphism 
$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a^2+b^2)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi) \oplus \mathbb{Z}[i]/(a-bi).$$
Here, cardinality of LHS is $(a^2+b^2)^2$ and RHS is sum of two conjugate copies of ring, hence each component has cardinality same, say $m$. Then 
$(a^2+b^2)^2=m^2$ implies $m=a^2+b^2$, the size of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$.

**Question 1.** What will happen if $(a+bi)$ and $(a-bi)$ are not relatively prime? How can I modify the answer?

**Question 2.** If $gcd(a,b)=1$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$), then is it always true that $(a+bi)$ and $(a-bi)$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

---

**Note:** The question about counting size of quotient ring of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has already posted earlier on this site; but, no answer there was in my direction. My question is about modification of my lines of answer for it.

Comment: Note that $1+i$ and $1-i$ are both divisible by $1+i$.

Comment: Here is another way to look at this:  The size of the quotient ring equal to the norm of the ideal, i.e. $N(I) = |\mathbb{O}/I|$.  And the norm of an principal ideal is equal to the norm of the element that generates it.  So let $I=(a+bi)$.  Then $|\mathbb{Z}[i]/I| = N(I) = N(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: I don't know how to modify your argument. But to answer your second question: This is false; take $a=b=1$. Then ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$, but $1+i = i\cdot (1-i)$, i. e. $i+1$ and $1-i$ are associated in $\mathbb Z[i]$. One can show that if ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$ and $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are not relatively prime, then both are divisible by $1+i$.

Comment: @John M: The fact that the norm of a principal ideal is the norm of its generator is precisely, what the OP asks to show (using his approach, I guess he is aware of a proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough idea which you can probably make a lot more elegant: I think one thing you can do to modify this argument is to use the fact that $A = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a principal ideal domain, and factor $z = a+bi$ into a product of primes.  **Assume that $z$ is not divisible by $1+i$**.An element $c+di$ is prime if and only if

(i): $d = 0$ and $c$ is a rational prime number which is $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

(ii): $c =0$ and $d$ is a rational prime number $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

(iii): $c, d \neq 0$ and $c^2 + d^2$ is a rational prime number.

So assuming say, $a, b \neq 0$, you can factor $a+bi$ into a product of primes $$p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_t^{e_t} (a_1 + b_1i)^{f_1} \cdots (a_s + b_si)^{f_s}$$ with $a_j + b_j i$ prime in $A$.  Then $a_j - b_j i, a_j + b_j i$ are relatively prime (the only exception occurs with something like $1+i$, which is an associate of $1-i$).  Now just argue as you did with $\frac{z}{p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_t^{e_t}}$.